# Basic Makefile for LaTeX Using Precompiled Preamble

Tags: latexmk, makefile

First, I realise that there are a lot of questions on this topic on TeX.SE. I have read through a lot of these, but have not been able to work out how to set up my current configuration.
I am very unfamiliar with the majority of the terms used and this is causing issues when I try to translate it from the set-up of the other questions to mine.
In particular, one that looked promising said that it does not work with `\input`, which I use.

My set-up is (I feel) pretty simple.
I have the following project.

```
main.tex
preamble_main.tex
preamble_aux.tex
```

I compile `main.tex` with the following command:

> `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex`.

`main.tex` contains `\input{premable_main.tex}` and `preamble_main.tex` contains `\input{preamble_aux.tex}`.
I pre-compile the passive preamble with the following command:

> `pdflatex -ini -jobname="main" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx main.tex`.

This creates a file called `main.fmt`.
This means that `main.tex` starts as follows:

```
%&main
\documentclass{CLASS}
\input{preamble_main.tex}
\endofdump
...
```

If I change `preamble_main.tex` (or `preamble_aux.tex` which is `\input` into `preamble_main.tex`), then this has no effect on the compilation of `main.tex` unless I recompile the preamble.

I would like to have a `make`-type file which does the following.

1. Check dates on `main.fmt` (`.fmt`, not `.tex` or `.pdf`), `preamble_main.tex` and `preamble_aux.tex`.
2. If either `preamble`s have been changed more recently than the `.fmt`, then run `pdflatex -ini -jobname="main" "&pdflatex" mylatexformat.ltx main.tex`.
3. (Whether or not the previous "if" held,) run `pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex`.

It certainly seems that `make` files or `latexmk` are suited for this *type* of question.
However, they seem to handle slightly different things.

Advice---or solutions!---would be most appreciated.

---

I'm not worried about setting up the bibliography stuff. I can easily handle this myself. Maybe in the future I try to improve it to handle that, but for now I just want the basics. Walk before you can run!

Comment: `%&preamble_main` here (on systems that read the magic comment) you are specifying the format is `preamble_main` but here `-jobname="main"` you are forcing it to be called `main`. You can call it anything you like but need to be consistent. rather than rely on the comment in the file I'd normally specify the format on the commandline so `pdflatex.exe  "&main" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "main".tex`

Comment: Ah, you are correct! This is just a typo in writing the question. I have corrected it now---that is, I have changed the start of the file to `%&main` rather than `%&preamble_main`. Thank you for spotting this. I shall also bear in mind your other suggestion. That seems like a pretty easy change to implement

Comment: IMO, this `mylatexformat` route (that I use a lot) is not intended for a  document with a frequently changing preamble. But as you use the `\endofdump` trick, you could simply `\input` the changing part of `preamble_aux.tex` between `\endofdump` and `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Yes, I agree that this should not be changing frequently. After `\endofdump`, I have the 'active' (let's call it) premable which I update---that section is quite short and didn't seem relevant to this question. I've changed the phrasing to call `preamble_main` now `preamble_passive` to emphasise that it doesn't change frequently. Just occasionally I do change stuff in the 'passive' preamble. It would be nice not to have to go and manually precompile it on these occasions---but it does change infrequently, so it's not the end of the world if I don't find a nice automated solution

Comment: Also, thanks for picking up the (rather careless) typo!

Comment: Ok, an answer was posted while I was changing `preamble_main` to `preamble_passive`. Thus I am reverting to `preamble_main`. Apologies for any confusion

Answer (score 6):

### Caveat emptor

Given that you are familiar with `latexmk` and `make`, I am not sure if suggesting another route is actually a sensible suggestion. In fact, suggesting another tool for this scenario is almost like throwing you in front of a moving bus (driven by a wacky duck). `:)`

In my defense, I blame one of the the developers ([who shall remain anonymous](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/124577/texnician)) for instigating me to write this answer. `:)`

---

This sounds like one of those specific scenarios in which a tool named `arara` might help. I am one of the developers involved in this tool and definitely biased towards it. Note that `arara` and `latexmk` are not exactly comparable, as each one works on different sides of the compilation/automation spectrum.

Let's tackle it with some conditionals inside your `main.tex`:

```
% This directive tackles your format rebuild

% arara: pdflatex: { options: ['-ini', '-jobname=main',
% arara: --> '&pdflatex', 'mylatexformat.ltx' ] } if
% arara: --> a = changed(toFile('preamble_main.tex'));
% arara: --> b = changed(toFile('preamble_aux.tex'));
% arara: -->  a || b

% Now, a proper compilation

% arara: pdflatex: { synctex: yes,
% arara: --> interaction: nonstopmode }

...
```

There we go! `:)`

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! (If I could give a second `+1` for the code-formatted emojis, I would!) I have an idea how to do this more directly with a `make` file. (I wasn't intending to _exclude_ the use of these. It just _appeared_ to me that they weren't quite suited. I have been informed otherwise.) I shall see if I can get a simpler solution directly. If I can, I can compare which I prefer. I'll also post the solution as an answer here so that others can see both. This is all assuming that I can get the `make` file to work as I am informed it should be able to...

Comment: @SamT updated! Phew it was easier than I thought. Sorry for the original noise. `:)`

Comment: Wow, that is much much simpler! Would I simply place this at the top of my `main.tex`?

Comment: @SamT yes, at the top of `main.tex` is usually recommended, but anywhere inside your file suffices. `:)` Two words of advice: the format will be rebuilt for the first time regardless because `arara` isn't currently tracking modification on those files, so it will think the files have changed (you can see the hashes in a generated file `arara.yaml`); and I could not test these commands as I never tried the format thingy, so please report if something bad happened...

Comment: I shall implement it, compare with a `make` approach and report back! Thanks for your time :)

Comment: My apologies for the delay in getting back to you on this. I haven't yet got around to doing the aforementioned `make` file. I still plan to! I shall post here once I have done so.

Comment: @SamT oh no worries! Take your time! The most important part is the journey itself, not the destination. `:)`